# Pandas Profiling 1.4 issue with Pycharm and windows 7 terminal

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, profiling, pandas-profiling

Showing this error while executing Pandas Profiling on pycharm or windows terminal

> Pycharm latest
>   Python version 3.6
>   Windows 7
>   Pandas profiling 1.4

```
pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(df) :
```

> RuntimeError: An attempt has been made to start a new process before
>   the current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.
>
> ```
> This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
> child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
> in the main module:
>
>     if __name__ == '__main__':
>         freeze_support()
>         ...
>
> The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
> is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

So the solution for the problem is as simple as the one below:

Added a main to my code and then in the end called if name statement to run. This solves my problem in quick easy steps.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_profiling
def main():
# my code for profiling
    df = pd.read_csv('csvfile')
    profile = pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(df)
    profile.to_file("profile.html")

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```